# Is it possible to use PostGIS on gisgraphy database?

Tags: postgis, gisgraphy

I have the entire [gisgraphy](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gisgraphy/) database inside my server. Is it possible to use PostGIS on it to query such as "get locations within 10 miles from this coordinate"?

I tried reading about spatial queries and PostGIS but I am not sure if I could directly use the tables in gisgraphy to obtain results.

Comment: Not familiar with the database, but the difference between "possible" / "can query" and "works at acceptable speed" is usually a spatial index. As for lynxlynxlynx's answer below, more reading of the docs may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find places around 10 miles is possible with the [find nearby webservice](http://www.gisgraphy.com/documentation/user-guide.htm#geolocservice). Find some examples on the [free access page](http://www.gisgraphy.com/free-access.htm)

The only thing you have to be aware is that gisgraphy use meter not miles (you have to do the conversion)

Answer (score 2):

Judging from its website at https://sourceforge.net/projects/gisgraphy/ it does support PostGIS and since you say you already made the import, querying should be a breeze. It doesn't sound like gisgraphy provides an extra interface for that, so you may need to do it on the postgres server directly.

The query itself is one of the most common ones, so please search this site for answers to that. Another very useful resource is the PostGIS reference at http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-2.0/reference.html, where you can check all the syntax details.